# Как подключить Android API в unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, 3d

Мне нужно подключить две библиотеки из API ОС Android. Первая для работы с файлами (открытие изображений и т. д.), а вторая для голосового ввода, распознавания голоса и перевода его в текст. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

если я правильно понял суть вопроса, то вот: https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/android-sdksetup.html